# Issue when serializing Map.Entry using jackson

Tags: serialization, junit, jackson, deserialization, junit4

If I try to deserialize below type stored as String:

```
 List<Entry<String, String>> entryList;
```

where entryList contains:

```
[{"dummyKey1":"dummyValue1"}]
```

I get the following errors

```
 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Map$Entry, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information.
```

I get above error while running a test case in junit, but if I  remove the test case, then after deploying everything runs fine :

Above error comes while running junit test case because of absence of NoArgsConstructor in Entry. So, I created a DummyEntry with NoArgsConstructor that calls Entry with arguments as null.

```
   DummyEntry<K, V> extends SimpleEntry<K, V>
```

After making this change, above error didn't come but I started getting below error after changes are deployed.

```
  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
  Unrecognized field "dummyKey1", not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "value", "key"]).
```

What is the reason that one way doesn't works for junit, but in production it works while other does work in junit but not in production.

Also, I noticed one additional thing: In production, Map.Entry is serialized to

```
  {'dummyKey1':'dummyValue1'}
```

whereas, test case in junit serializes the same string as

```
 {'key':'dummyKey1', 'value':'dummyValue1'}
```

What is the reason about this weird behavior ? How can I make this thing work for both ?

Comment: What version of jackson-databind library is in use in (a) production and (b) your test case?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might be encountering an issue with different serialisation strategies for `Map.Entry`.

In v2.5.0 (IIRC) of jackson-databind [Map.Entry was supported as a 'known type'](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/565). Prior to this version, the `key` and `value` attributes of Map.Entry would appear in a serialised Map.Entry. After this version, that's no longer the case.

Here are some example test cases showing what I mean:

```
@Test
public void mapSerialisationPreJackson2_5_0() throws IOException {
  Map<String, String> aMap = Maps.newHashMap();
  aMap.put("dummyKey1", "dummyValue1");

  Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> incoming = aMap.entrySet();

  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  String serialised = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(incoming);

  // prints: [{"key":"dummyKey1","value":"dummyValue1"}]
  System.out.println(serialised);

  Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> deserialised = objectMapper.readValue(serialised, Set.class);

  // prints: [{key=dummyKey1, value=dummyValue1} (just like you posted in your question) whereas for versions > 2.5.0 the serialised form is ]
  System.out.println(deserialised);
}

@Test
public void mapSerialisationPostJackson2_5_0() throws IOException {
  Map<String, String> aMap = Maps.newHashMap();
  aMap.put("dummyKey1", "dummyValue1");

  Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> incoming = aMap.entrySet();

  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  String serialised = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(incoming);

  // prints: [{"dummyKey1":"dummyValue1"}]
  System.out.println(serialised);

  Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> deserialised = objectMapper.readValue(serialised, Set.class);

  // prints: [{dummyKey1=dummyValue1}]
  System.out.println(deserialised);
}
```

Prior to v2.5.0 a Map.Entry would be serialised to `{key=dummyKey1, value=dummyValue1}` (just like you posted in your question) whereas for versions > 2.5.0 the serialised form is `{dummyKey1=dummyValue1}`.

I think you are using a version of jackson-databind in your test context which is < 2.5.0 and a version of jackson-databind in your production context which is > 2.5.0

Comment: I am using jackson 2.8 . I haven't added previous version of jackson for test context. I saw this link https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-databind/issues/565  earlier, which is same as your information. I am not able to figure out why junit is picking older version of jackson when I have specified dependency on jackson 2.8

Comment: How are you managing dependencies? Are you using Maven? Gradle? It sounds like you have a different of jackson-databind on your test's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to deserialize `[{"dummyKey1":"dummyValue1"}]` into a `List<Entry<String, String>>` variable you can:

1. Use Jackson's parameter names module. Read more [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names). It basically allows non-annotated, non default constructors with parameters to be used for deserialization of a class. In this case the constructors of the various implementations of `Map.Entry`. A perfectly straightforward solution if you use Java 8 anyway.
2. If you can't use the parameter names module (e.g. Java 7), you can look into using [mixins](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) to annotate a constructor of a class without modifying it's source code. I had a go at that and it's tricky. For `HashMap` for instance the implementation of `Map.Entry` is `Node` which has package private visibility.